# How to change the date format for a mailing token for a custom date field

Tags: custom-fields, tokens, dates

We have a date field, custom, set to be dd-mm-yyyy but when we add a token for that custom field in a mailing it comes out as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

How do we change this

Comment: Of course, you know the answer to this question ... a custom extension. Seems like custom field tokens are not formatting the value of the custom field, just outputting it, at least in the case of dates. I'm not convinced that is wrong.

Comment: Only a year later! See my answer to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/38686/446 and let me know if it's a solution you'd like to see here.